# How to find existing pipeline in Kurento?

Tags: kurento

I have an app server that's using kurento-client for integration purposes.

To be specific, I'll be taking streams from IP Cams and record them using PlayerEndpoint and RecorderEndpoint.

Now, in case my app server is dead/killed, the pipeline in KMS will continue recording, how do I find that existing pipeline?

Side question, how can I instruct KMS to record the streams in chunk of 15 minutes (or any period)? The only way I can think of is probably manual start/stop the RecorderEndpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per answer from Kurento's mailing list.

```
kurentoClient.getServerManager().getMediaPipelines()
```

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.kurento.client.KurentoClient&method=getServerManager

[Original answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/kurento/CAFXW_DvUjRDr-hUsepEx8Pj5ipcymETJ81BgkDY_Bk8%3Dhc%2B9Tw%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer)